# Ubuntu QT install qt quick controls 2.1

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, terminal, qml

I have a Qt 5.7.0 application. When I run my application it does not start and there is a terminal message saying:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Controls" version 2.1 is not installed
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: what is your qt version?

Comment: @eyllanesc Qt 5.7.0

Comment: How have you installed qt?

Comment: execute: `sudo apt-get install qml-module-qtquick-controls`

Comment: @eyllanesc Following this guide https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu until command sudo "apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev -y", nothing more

Comment: @eyllanesc terminal still giving me the same answer

Comment: change `import QtQuick.Controls x.y` to `import QtQuick.Controls 1.4`

Comment: @eyllanesc but I need qml properties that the 1.4 does not accept...

Comment: For this you need the latest version of Qt, download version 5.9: http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/5.9.1/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.9.1.run

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, this fixed it for me: sudo apt-get install qml-module-qtquick-controls2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from [the "Versions" section of the Qt Quick Controls 2 documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-index.html#versions), you have to import version 2.0 of Quick Controls if you're using Qt 5.7, *not* version 2.1 of Quick Controls.

Alternatively, you could update to the latest version of Qt (5.9), and then you can use Quick Controls 2.1.

Comment: Your answer doesn't state how someone would update to Qt 5.9